# Simplify kotlin method calling

Tags: lambda, kotlin

Please look at the code:

```
suspend fun <T : Any?> await(f: (Handler<AsyncResult<T>>) -> Unit) : T {
    return awaitResult<T> {
        f(it)
    }
}    
await<Account> { accountService.get(1, it) } // (*)
```

Is it possible to rewrite (*) line in this way (I want to eliminate of ugly "it" syntax):

```
await<Account>(accountService.get(1))
// or just
await<Account> accountService.get(1)
```

Comment: is `account(1)` supposed to be equal to `{ accountService.get(1, it) }`?

Comment: yep, I'll update my topic to clarify

Comment: Guess you have to write another function that will wrap your await call, something like `awaitAccount(Int)`. You can't entirely get rid of `accountService.get(n, it)` because it's body of asynchronous method.

Comment: I'm baffled by the seemingly backward usage of coroutines. Why on Earth would you pass a callback to `await` when that's precisely the thing coroutines and `suspend fun`s were invented to eliminate?

Comment: @Pawel At this moment I have Java interface with method where callback is the last parametr, than I create extension methods with methods name xyzAwait(). But I want to find a better solution than creating extension methods for each interface it seems redundant

Comment: You probably want to simplify the code, not just how you call it